# How to add a dependency for a specific device type in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dependencies, barcode-scanner

My issue is pretty tricky (I think). I'm working on a project on which the user can scan barcodes thanks to a scanner device (so without cameras). This part being fully  functional, I wanted to add a specific feature to scan barcodes with the camera, for the phone devices. The issue is that if I do that, using dependecies because I don't know how do to it myself, the permission hardware.android.camera (something like that) is automaticaclly added. Therefore, Google play doesn't allows me to publish my app for the original type of devices: scanners.

I would like to know if there is a solution to my problem (I didn't find anything by now from my researchs). It could be a kind of flavor, allowing me to have different dependencies and files for different apps, but keeping the same base code. Or a dependecy/tuto that gives me the opportunity to check if the device has cameras, so then ask for camera permission.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you can't add a dependency for a specific user.